# Download time-out when connection is down

Tags: c#, download, timeout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Timeout when connection is gone. HELP ME PLEASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666152/timeout-when-connection-is-gone-help-me-please)

I'd like to put in my code a time-out.
When the file is being downloaded and i stay without internet, it count to 60 secs and if the connection don't back, gives a message.

Here is the code:

```
    string novoNome;
    novoNome = strlocal + "\\" + zipNome;
    using (WebClient wcDownload = new WebClient())
    { 
          try
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(strlocal))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(strlocal);
                }

                #region comunicação para download
                //string saida;
                // cria uma requisição do arquivo para download
                webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

                webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();                    

                //Perguntar o tamanho do arquivo
                Int64 fileSize = webResponse.ContentLength;

                Uri uri = new Uri(url);

                // Abrindo arquivo para Download
                strResponse = wcDownload.OpenRead(uri);
                // Criando novo arquivo para salvar no HDD
                strLocal = new FileStream(novoNome, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
                #endregion

                #region transferencia
                int bytesSize = 0;

                byte[] downBuffer = new byte[2048];                   

                try
                {
                    while ((bytesSize = strResponse.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {                           
                        strLocal.Write(downBuffer, 0, bytesSize);
                        //if(this.IsAccessible)
                        this.Invoke(new UpdateProgessCallback(this.UpdateProgress), new object[] { strLocal.Length, fileSize });
                        //wcDownload.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wcDownload_DownloadProgressChanged);                              
                    }                        
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
                #endregion                    
            }                
            finally
            {
                strResponse.Close();
                strLocal.Close();
            }
        }
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What problem are you seeing with the code posted?

Comment: This should be handled by default by the underline tcp connection.

Comment: The code have no problem. I just want to know which line I have to change or add to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timeout on your `WebRequest` instance. Something like: `webRequest.Timeout=60000;`
In case of a timeout, a  `WebException` will be thrown. Check the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.timeout.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You should set Timeout property to WebRequest class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.timeout.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are two timeout that you can set one is the aforementioned answer which is setting the webRequest.Timeout. Another one which would be useful in your case is :

```
webResponse.GetResponseStream().ReadTimeout = 60000;
```

which will throw an exception while your internet connection is gone for 60s....

Comment: It's exactly what I want! But, how could I handle this exception? Could you see my code and show me where I have to put this code line? and how to handle the exception that it throws. Thank's a lot!

Comment: Didn't worked! Help me please!! T.T