# Timeout when connection is gone. HELP ME PLEASE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, timer, download, timeout

I'd like to put in my code a time-out. When the file is being downloaded and i stay without internet, it count to 60 secs and if the connection don't back, gives a message.

Here is the code:

```
string novoNome;
novoNome = strlocal + "\\" + zipNome;
using (WebClient wcDownload = new WebClient())
{ 
      try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(strlocal))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(strlocal);
            }

            #region comunicação para download
            //string saida;
            // cria uma requisição do arquivo para download
            webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            webRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 60000;

            webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();                    

            //Perguntar o tamanho do arquivo
            Int64 fileSize = webResponse.ContentLength;

            Uri uri = new Uri(url);

            // Abrindo arquivo para Download
            strResponse = wcDownload.OpenRead(uri);
            // Criando novo arquivo para salvar no HDD
            strLocal = new FileStream(novoNome, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            #endregion

            #region transferencia
            int bytesSize = 0;

            byte[] downBuffer = new byte[2048];                   

            try
            {
                while ((bytesSize = strResponse.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                {                           
                    strLocal.Write(downBuffer, 0, bytesSize);
                    //if(this.IsAccessible)
                    this.Invoke(new UpdateProgessCallback(this.UpdateProgress), new object[] { strLocal.Length, fileSize });
                    //wcDownload.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wcDownload_DownloadProgressChanged);                              
                }                        
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {                        
                MessageBox.Show("WEB ERROO:" + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro:" + e.Message);
            }
            #endregion
            }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("WEB ERROO:" + ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro:" + e.Message);
        }                            
        finally
        {
            strResponse.Close();
            strLocal.Close();
        }
    }
```

Sorry bad English, I'm Brazilian.

PLEASE HELP!!

Thank's.

Comment: Have you considered reading asynchronously, and cutting that connection when your personal timer reads 60 seconds?

Comment: Maybe [WebRequest.Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.timeout.aspx) is the property you are looking for or [HttpWebRequest.ReadWriteTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.readwritetimeout.aspx).

Comment: Brazilian or not, please do not write "HELP ME PLEASE" and "PLEASE HELP" in your posts. People will help (this is what this site is for), just post your question clearly and concisely and give them a chance.

Comment: As a small stylisitc point, if your method's so large or complex that your trying to seperate it out with regions, you may want to consider refactoring some blocks out to seperate functions...

Comment: Jason, I already tried to use a timer counting to 60, but didn't work. Another idea? Thanks

Comment: lngenu, this property it's to all the request. I want one only to when the internet connection is gone. Thanks

Comment: adelphus, sorry I'm new on this site. But that is the 3° question with the same problem and anyone couldn't help me. I'm getting crazy.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you do not need a custom timeout handling implementation for this. Try out setting `webRequest.Timeout` property to 60000.

To specify the amount of time to wait before a read or write operation times out, use the [ReadWriteTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.readwritetimeout.aspx) property.

Important

> The Timeout property must be set before the GetRequestStream or
>   GetResponse method is called. Changing the Timeout property after
>   calling the GetRequestStream or GetResponse method has no effect

EDIT:

If you are looking for a custom timeout handling you still can leverage built in `Timeout` as well. So just handle a `WebException` and then analyze exeption Status property whcih could indicate what caused timeout. There are different status codes could be so just emulate it on local machine by disconnecting a network (simulate network connection lost) and see what is the status, then you can add some code to handle this scenario and launch custom timer for 60seconds).

I believe you need to handle following statuses:

- **ConnectFailure**: The remote service point could not be contacted at the transport level.
- **Timeout**: No response was received during the time-out period for a request.

See all available statuses: [WebExceptionStatus Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus.aspx)

Please let me know if you need more details or something is not clear.

Comment: This timeout is to all the download. I need one to start count only when the internet connection is gone.

Comment: See EDIT part for update

Comment: I did set the readwriteTimeout property, handled a web exception and simulated a connection lost but nothing happened.

Comment: I edited the code take a look please.

Comment: It makes sense print `exception.Status` along with message as well. So have you catched any errors when disconnected a network connection?

Comment: That's the problem. Nothing happened. Any exception... Did you see the code? Could anything be wrong on it?